# Move RSS folder from Junk Mail folder in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Somehow (I have no idea how), the RSS Feeds special folder was moved to the Junk Email folder in Outlook. Is there any way to get it back to the normal location and not as a subfolder?

Comment: Have you tried dragging the folder to "Inbox" at the top?

Comment: @vCole: Yes, but then Microsoft Outlook tells me that I can't move special folders... not sure how it let me move it in there in the first place.